# Way to play videos captured from iPhone on Android device?

Tags: android, iphone-video

I am aware that some unsupported .MP4 videos doesn't play in Android.

Video is recorded from default camera app in iPhone and shared to android device.

I've also checked for any available answers. I found FFmpeg library. I guess it is used to stream online videos but I want to play local video stored on SDcard.

I tried to fire an intent and let user choose to play video from any installed player eg. mxPlayer. It shows the error "can't play video" but after clicking on OK it starts playing the same video. Other players like vlc n moboplayer doesn't play the video.

So is there a way to play every recorded video from iPhone in Android?

Comment: Have you tried with VLC player? it's based on FFmeg if I remember well

Comment: Also you could use the FFmpeg library to re-encode the video in the format that you want

Comment: @arthur_gg: Yeah I did but vlc player doesn't plays the video n shuts down

Comment: @arthur_gg: I don't know much about video re-encoding using ffmpeg. Is there a way to do so in android? Some help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: Yes it's possible I managed to do it. I would recommend you first to try on your local machine before integrating the library in your Android project. https://www.ffmpeg.org/   you have tons of options

Comment: @arthur_gg: can u simply share the Demo?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68932/discussion-between-arthur-gg-and-kevz).